# Call Firebase.initializeApp() not listening , still it throws error "No Core default app found....Call Firebase.initializeApp()"

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have tried initializing in Main() but problem is persistent
Have checked all config files
Have checked firebase console

```
void main() {
        runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDirected();
  }

  Future<void> getDirected() async {
    
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    new Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
        print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
        return Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MyRoutes.homeRoute);
      } else {
        return Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MyRoutes.loginRoute);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

put these lines in main function

```dart
void main() async{
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
     await Firebase.initializeApp();
     runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

You should convert main to async and await for initialize app there.

Comment: Did you fix this?